# Atualizar "Validators" utilizando "Directive"

Tags: javascript, angular

## Meu código

Criei a seguinte diretiva para impedir que o usuário insira caracteres especiais em inputs.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFilterSpecialCharacters]'
})
export class FilterSpecialCharactersDirective {

  regexStr = "\\W|_";
  regex = new RegExp(this.regexStr);

  constructor() {}

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return !this.regex.test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(new RegExp(this.regexStr, "g"), "");
  }

}
```

Este é um exemplo de `input` utilizando a diretiva

```
<input appFilterSpecialCharacters type="text" id="inputCep" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Entre com o CEP do filiado" formControlName="cep" required autofocus>
```

E estou com a validação da seguinte maneira

```
public formulario: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    'matriculacpf': new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(11),
        Validators.maxLength(11)
    ])
});
```

## Meu problema

A diretiva esta se comportando como previsto, impedindo que o usuário entre com caracteres especiais, o problema acontece quando o usuário cola um cep.

Vamos supor que o usuário cole "35900777", a validação identifica que o cep tem 8 dígitos e deixa passar, porem se colar "35900-777" a validação identifica que tem 9 dígitos e não deixa passar.

Ou seja o usuário cola "35900-777", a validação identifica 9 dígitos a diretiva remove o "-" porem a validação "não percebe" esta alteração e continua bloqueando mesmo depois da diretiva passar o valor para "35900777".

Queria inserir algo na diretiva para atualizar a validação, para que identifique que o cep esta certo depois da alteração.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solução

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira, no construtor eu injeto um `NgControl`

```
constructor(private control : NgControl) { }
```

Então eu alterei a seguinte linha

```
event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(new RegExp(this.regexStr, "g"), "");
```

Por

```
this.control.control.setValue(event.target.value.replace(new RegExp(this.regexStr, "g"), ""));
```

Assim você consegue alterar o `FormControl` e consequentemente a validação consegue identificar a sua alteração.

Fonte [Angular2 v.2.3 - Have a directive access a FormControl created through formControlName syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171686/angular2-v-2-3-have-a-directive-access-a-formcontrol-created-through-formcontr)

## Código completo da diretiva

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFilterSpecialCharacters]'
})
export class FilterSpecialCharactersDirective {

  regexStr = "\\W|_";
  regex = new RegExp(this.regexStr);

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return !this.regex.test(event.key);
  }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
    this.control.control.setValue(event.target.value.replace(new RegExp(this.regexStr, "g"), ""));
  }

}
```